# jquery navigation color and follow the page on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, colors, navigation, uinavigationbar

I'm looking to change the color of the nav bar and the color of the texts of the nav like in his website: http://duotones.ch/ I searched but only found about changing the size not the background like from transparent to some collor, and thare is a point that follows what page I am at the moment, any help would be great.

A jsfiddle demo would be awesome!

Comment: You need to try something first, then when you run into a particular problem, you ask a question and YOU provide code and YOU provide a fiddle for US to play with and solve your problem. [**READ THIS**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have the following css rules for the nav-bar:

```
.navbar.contentNav {
    background-color: rgba(176,252,229,.9);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.04);
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

change background-color, the last parameter of rgba is opacity.

the text color is controlled with css rule color. here is your css rules for the nav-bar text color:

```
li.active a {
    color: #3d3d3c!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
but check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/N5dsa/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('li').hover(function(){
       $(this).css({'background-color':'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'})
       },function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'rgba(255,0,0,0.0)'})   
    })
})
</script>
```

If you want that items in the navigation bar  change colour from tansparent to a pre-established color you could use transition in css and hover method in jQuery